# scrollToLocation is undefined in sectionlist ref of react native, neither in flatlist

Tags: react-native

I have tried Flatlist, SectionList, Animated.Flatlist and Animated.SectionList,
Here is a simple example how to check scrollToLocation:

```
<SectionList 
     onLayout={this.onLayout.bind(this)}
     ref={ref => {
     this.sectionList = ref
     console.log('ref.scrollToLocation: ' + CircularJSON.stringify(ref.scrollToLocation))
          } }
     ListHeaderComponent={() => <View style={{height:300, width:300, backgroundColor:'green'}}></View>}
     sections = {[{key: 1, data: [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]}]}
     renderItem = {() => <View style={{width:300, height: 100, marginBottom:20, backgroundColor:'red'}}></View>}
        />
```

Expected to see scrollToLocation method but showing ***`undefined`***.
Please help me if you have any idea. Thanks!

```
Env:
"react": "16.6.3",
"react-native": "0.57.8",
Simulator: Xcode 10 iPhone X
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Implementing This Way.

```js
this.SectionList.scrollToLocation({sectionIndex,itemIndex})

render(){
return(<SectionList 
   ref={ref=>{this.SectionList = ref}}
   otherProps
/>)
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, the real issue is about Animated.Sectionlist, the way to get ref is certainly different:         this.SectionListRef.getNode().scrollToLocation({sectionIndex:0,itemIndex:0, viewOffset: 40})